# How to total the number of selected columns that have string data?

Tags: list, column, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, count

Within a SharePoint Online list, if I have a record that has 6 columns like so...

```
ID: #id of this record
Title: "my first test" 
Step 1: "apple" 
Step 2: "grape"
Step 3:
Sum: 2
```

or in another way

```
ID: #id of this reord
Title: "my first test" 
Step 1: "apple" 
Step 2: "grape"
Step 3: "jelly"
Sum: 3
```

How can I have a column `Sum:` that prints the total number of other `Step_x:` columns that has a string value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a calculated column with a formula like:

```
=COUNTA([Step1], [Step2], [Step3])
```

Details here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14)#count-nonblank-columns

---

Alternatively, you can do this with column formatting with a format like this:

```
{
  "elmType": "span",
  "txtContent": "=if([$Step1],1,0) + if([$Step2],1,0) + if([$Step3],1,0)"
}
```

Comment: Your first answer was good enough for my situation.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use any one of the below formulas in your calculated column:

```
="Sum: " & COUNTA([Step 1], [Step 2], [Step 3])
```

OR

```
=CONCATENATE("Sum: ", COUNTA([Step 1], [Step 2], [Step 3]))
```

**References**:

1. [CONCATENATE function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/concatenate-function-5b0392b2-94ef-49ea-8532-4fdd3a69d362)
2. [Count nonblank columns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14)#count-nonblank-columns)